# run nodejs script in godaddy shared hosting

Tags: node.js, shared-hosting

I have a Godaddy shared hosting and I want to run a very little nodejs script. I would like to know if I can install nodejs like I did for GIT following this [tutorial](http://www.adamboother.com/blog/install-git-on-a-godaddy-shared-hosting-account/)

Comment: https://github.com/niutech/node.php check this

Comment: The person has made whole method to do that.

Comment: Is your node.js script means to be a long running server process?  Or just a script that performs some operation and then exits?

Comment: just a script that performs some operation and then exits